# Scaffoldmessenger widget ancestor problem

Tags: flutter

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SharedPrefs.init();
  runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserProvider()),
        Provider(
          create: (context) => AuthService(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return const MyApp();
      })));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<AuthService>().getUserData(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Amazon Clone',
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) => generateRoute(settings),
        theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: GlobalVariables.backgroundColor,
          colorScheme:
              const ColorScheme.light(primary: GlobalVariables.secondaryColor),
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            elevation: 0,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        home: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return context.watch<UserProvider>().user.token.isNotEmpty
              ? const HomeScreen()
              : const AuthScreen();
        }));
  }
}
```

i am using snackbar from utils file i get no scaffoldmessenger widget found error.I tried to use builder scaffoldmessengerkey but didnt work.what can i do.i used try catch with snackbar.What is the solve of my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need both `MaterialApp` and a `Scaffold` widget in the tree before using `ScaffoldMessenger`. For example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(  // required MaterialApp
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(   // required Scaffold
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatelessWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('A SnackBar has been shown.'),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But probably snackbar fail coming initstate method context.read,what can we do?

Comment: Where are you calling showSnackBar then?

Comment: Well you should not call that method from initState :)